# Indents added to span when generated by PHP

Tags: php, html, aptana, dreamweaver

I'm having a bad time with indenting my PHP code, I used to have this code:

```
<span>
<?php
    echo 'test';
?>
</span>
```

Generate something like this:

```
<span>test</span>
```

And now for some reason it's generating something like this:

```
<span>    test    </span>
```

I've switched from Dreamweaver to Aptana a few weeks ago so now I'm wondering if it has something to do with this, like text encoding or FTP connexions? I've already tried to fiddle with Aptana's settings (change tab to spaces, set tabs to be tabs) but can get it to work the way I want.

Any idea what I could do to solve this problem?

EDIT: This is just example code. I can't write everything on one line as it needs to be readably for maintenance purposes.

Comment: So write it in a single line `<span><?php echo 'test'; ?></span>`

Comment: I know this would be an option... but in my case I need to keep these indents to have readable code.

Comment: `<span><?php (NEWLINE) (all your code) (NEWLINE) ?></span>`

Comment: I just found out that in prior versions of our CMS there where PHP tags to skip the tabulations. @CarlosCampderrós: if you put your comment as an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the opening and closing php tags next to the `<span>` tags, the php code in their own lines:

```
<span><?php
   echo 'test';
?></span>
```